# Reference request for line arrangements, duality, k-levels

Tags: reference-request, projective-geometry, computational-geometry, plane-geometry

As in title question, I'm looking for a reference for the basic facts regarding arrangements of lines in the real plane, geometric duality, k levels and associated combinatorics. Some applications to algorithms would be a plus.

I prefer clarity and intuition over comprehensiveness. Something suitable for an undergraduate would be ideal.

Maybe someone can recommend a book or notes they had a positive experience with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Berg/Cheong/... "Computational geometry: Algorithms and Applications" and Edelsbrunner "Algorithms in Computational Geometry" have most of what I am looking for.